# Add "Add to Path" to context menu

Tags: windows-10, path, context-menu

I tried to use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/266974/any-freeware-program-for-adding-editing-path-from-context-menu) solution but it is outdated seeing as I use Windows 10 but I was wondering if there is anyway to add a option in the context menu to add a folder to the PATH because it is very annoying to keep modifying the PATH over and over again

Comment: context menu of what (explorer?) and what path (windows environment variable?)?

Comment: Yes Explorer and the environment variable

Comment: Adding things to your path makes everything run slower.  Every time 'something' is opened and a path isn't provided.. windows has to search each and every one of them for the thing.  It may seem convenient.. but it comes at a cost.  There is a reason that it isn't quick to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered in Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269312/adding-a-shell-context-menu-item-so-that-i-can-add-folder-to-path-by-right-click

> Managed to find a permanent solution. Since setx sets the user path
>   and not the system path, the command mentioned in my question will add
>   all elements in the combined userpath + system path to PATH,
>   effectively doubling its size every time you run the script.
>
> This can either be fixed by removing user path, or as I did, add
>   another user variable and append that to path. I then ended up with
>   the following script afterwards to set the path correctly:
>
> ```
> cmd /k setx UPATH "%%UPATH%%;%1%" && exit
> ```
>
> This way I don't need to use a bat-file. Using double %s and &s seem
>   to work as a way to escape the character, thus making it look like
>   this to cmd:
>
> ```
> setx UPATH "%UPATH%;drive:/theFolderYouRightClicked" & exit
> ```
>
> I am still not sure why you have to pass this through cmd in order to
>   see the PATH-variable, but at least this is a semi-clean way of
>   solving my problem